# Pull and slide along edges simultaneously

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, vertices, coordinates

Is it possible to slide multiple vertices along edges that point towards a certain point? As demonstrated in the first picture, I would like to slide the selected along the edges on the direction shown by the arrows, but simultaneously, so they are all equidistant from the center (without merging them).

[image: Picture 1]

The problem is that if I select them and slide them on the edges at the same time, they slide in the direction of my mouse cursor, and therefore will slide in different directions, as show in the second picture.

[image: Picture 2]

Push/pull would indeed bring them closer, but without sliding on the edges (basically only bringing them close on 2 axes). Is there any way to accomplish what both push/pull and slide do, simultaneously? Or another effective way of doing this transformation?

Comment: If I've got you correctly, one way to do that is to select that central point to which you'd like to slide vertices, snap cursor to it with `Shift` + `S` and scale those vertices with `Pivot Point` set to `3D Cursor`.

Comment: @MrZak Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm not looking to scale the vertices but rather to slide them along edges, just like you would do with SHIFT + V  granted, the result is close to the same on the example above but I made simple screenshots to exemplify the problem. My actual problem is with a UV sphere with many more vertices. If I scale them, they will dig into the sphere, whereas I need the vertices to move onto the surface along edges. But I was ALSO looking at how to make transformations towards the 3D cursor, and you did learn me something new that I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: You then should present problem with sphere actually, becuase what you've asked maybe done as I said. Still, with sphere you may try select one vertice, use `Shift` + `V` (or `G` twice) and enter exact number to slide it. And so whith every vertice you'd like to slide.